# Performance Issue with "Nop Ajax filter Pro"

Tags: nopcommerce-4.2

We have 1 million products. We are using “The Ajax Filter Pro Pack” wherein combination we are using is “Category & Manufactures and Specification”

The challenge is we are facing a huge wait time of 15 seconds to filter and display the products.

We need to resolve it and bring it down to 2 seconds as its effecting our customer experience badly.